# Linux process monitoring daemon

Tags: linux, process, monitoring

I'm often issuing commands that take some time. For example downloading something using a console download app. If I want to be noticed when the command has finished, I usually do something like this:

```
$ <do something>; echo '<do something> has finished' | osd_cat
```

Then I can switch to another window and do something else meanwhile. When it's done, I'll be noticed.

Now my problem is that **I'm lazy**. Oh well. I just don't want to type this everytime. So I wonder if there's a daemon that could watch running processes and trigger some actions when the processes finish.

I would like config options so I could have control on:

1. filtering the processes to be watched (for example, watch processes that run at least for a minute)
2. customizing the command to perform when a process has finished

Comment: [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#DESCRIPTION) might work for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

You could try using Bash's "wait" command to write a little wrapper script
Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
command=$*

$command &  
wait
osd_cat "$command has finished"
```

The wait command causes the script to pause until all child processes have returned an exit code.
You could also add a little timeout to make sure that you don't wait too long

Answer (score 0):

How about just a simple shell script that does the long command for you. Maybe something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# tellme: run a command and tell me when it's done
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    if $*; then
        echo "'$*' has finished" | osd_cat
    else
        echo "'$*' has finished with errors" | osd_cat
    fi
else
    echo "usage: $0 <command>"
fi
```

Then, you would just run this command:

> `tellme <do something>`

Granted, it isn't a daemon, so I don't think it will help you for things started in the background (e.g. from cron), but it should do the job for interactive commands.

Comment: It's still more to type than just the command itself. That's why I'm wondering if there's a daemon that would work absolutely transparently.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not a daemon, but it serves the same purpose for me. `zsh` has scriptable hooks executed right before and right after executing any command. You can make them measure wallclock time and run any action (here: `notify-send`) if the last executed command was long enough. The following in an excerpt from my `~/.zshrc`:

```
preexec () {
  ZSH_CMD_START_TIME="$(date +%s)"
  ZSH_CMD_NAME="$1"
}
precmd () {
  [[ -n "$ZSH_CMD_NAME" ]] && {
    ZSH_LAST_TIME=$(($(date +%s) - $ZSH_CMD_START_TIME))
    [[ $ZSH_LAST_TIME -gt 60 ]] && [[ -n "$DISPLAY" ]] && { which >/dev/null notify-send } && {
      notify-send --urgency=low --category=zsh --expire-time 1500 "ZSH:" '`'"$ZSH_CMD_NAME"'`'" took $ZSH_LAST_TIME seconds."
    }
    ZSH_CMD_NAME=
  }
}
```